# JOIN issues on mySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Two tables, brand_gifts bg, giftcode gc:

**Table 1: brand_gifts**

```
id brand_id name
```

**Table 2: giftcode**

```
id gift_id code usesleft
```

The value I use to retrieve my data is the brand_id from brand_gifts table. What I need is a list of elements that on table one brand_id = 1, the two tables are related by table1:id table2: gift_id (not necesary all the elements on table1 have a relation with table2, in other words, not alls ids from table one have a gift_id on table2), so using that relation i want to query all brand_id = 1 where also usesleft > 0.

I tried this:

```
SELECT gc.gift_id
FROM brand_gifts bg, giftcode gc
WHERE (
bg.brand_id =1
AND gc.gift_id = gc.id
AND gc.usesleft >0
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

But the result is wrong.

Comment: In what sense in the result of the stated query wrong - what data is it producing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT gc.gift_id
    FROM brand_gifts bg, giftcode gc
   WHERE (
    bg.brand_id =1
    AND gc.gift_id = gc.id    <==
   AND gc.usesleft >0
   )
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

your error looks in the marked line, the condition should be "gc.gift_id = bg.id"

```
   SELECT gc.gift_id
    FROM brand_gifts bg, giftcode gc
   WHERE (
    bg.brand_id =1
    AND gc.gift_id = bg.id    <==
   AND gc.usesleft >0
  )
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT gc.gift_id
FROM brand_gifts bg, giftcode gc
WHERE (
bg.brand_id =1
AND gc.gift_id = bg.id
AND gc.usesleft >0
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT gc.gift_id
FROM giftcode gc
LEFT JOIN brand_gifts bg
ON gc.gift_id = bg.id
WHERE gc.usesleft > 0
```